# a format breaker on the website stops my Scrapy spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

my Scrapy Spider stops working when it meets a website format outlier. Here is the website element that go WRONG (the highlighted part):
[image]

The correct one has an 'a' attribution. it looks like below ((the highlighted part)):
[image]

And here is my Spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "name"
  allowed_domains = ["website domain"]
  start_urls = ['Mywebsite link']

  def parse(self, response):
    self.log('I just visited: ' + response.url)

    for i in response.css('tr.odd'):
        item = {
            'company_name': i.css('td > a::text')[0].extract(),
            'ABN': i.css('td > a::text')[1].extract(),
            'status': i.css('td::text')[2].extract(),
            'size': i.css('td::text')[3].extract(),
            'suburb/town': i.css('td::text')[4].extract(),
            'state': i.css('td::text')[5].extract(),
        }
        yield item

    for i in response.css('tr.even'):
        item = {
            'company_name': i.css('td > a::text')[0].extract(),
            **'ABN': i.css('td > a::text')[1].extract()**,     # this part stops working
            'status': i.css('td::text')[2].extract(),
            'size': i.css('td::text')[3].extract(),
            'suburb/town': i.css('td::text')[4].extract(),
            'state': i.css('td::text')[5].extract(),
        }
        yield item

    # follow pagination link
    next_page_url = response.css('li.next > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page_url:
        next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

On the website it looks like this:
[image]
The 'information unavailable' part in that row stops my spider. Please show me what should I do. Thank you!

Comment: Your code expects 6 links within a `td`. The input HTML you should only has 1 (and it’s not the company name). Consider rewriting your row extraction from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Did you write the code you are now trying to fix? Do you understand what `i.css('td > a::text')[n].extract()` does, given the input HTML that your screenshots show? (ps: screenshots of code are discouraged)

Comment: url: https://www.acnc.gov.au/charity?items_per_page=10&name_abn%5B0%5D=surf%20club&location%5B0%5D=qld&facet__select__field_beneficiaries=0&facet__select__field_countries=0&facet__select__acnc_search_api_sub_history=0&facet__select__field_status=0

Comment: The top code is the actual website code,
i was under the impression that my loop would grab the text of the td class and give me the information such as the legal name and ABN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by rewriting my codes. Thanks to all the answer-contributors. Special thanks to @Gallaecio. Here is my solution:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class AcncSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "spider_name"
  allowed_domains = ["url"]
  start_urls = ['url']

  def parse(self, response):
    self.log('I just visited: ' + response.url)

    for i in response.css('div.view-content > div > table > tbody > tr.odd'):

        item = {
            'company_name': i.css('td.views-field.views-field-acnc-search-api-title-sort > a::text').extract(),
             
            'status': i.css('td.views-field.views-field-acnc-search-api-status-normalised::text').extract(),
            
            'size': i.css('td.views-field.views-field-field-charity-size.views-align-center::text').extract(),
             
            'suburb/town': i.css('td.views-field.views-field-acnc-search-api-address-locality::text').extract(),
            
            'state': i.css('td.views-field.views-field-acnc-search-api-address-administrative-area::text').extract(),
             
            'ABN': i.css('td.views-field.views-field-acnc-search-api-abn-sort > a::text').extract(),

            'URL': response.urljoin(i.css('td.views-field.views-field-acnc-search-api-title-sort > a::attr(href)').extract_first()),
                   
        }
        yield item
    
    for i in response.css('div.view-content > div > table > tbody > tr.even'):

        item = { 
            'company_name': i.css('td.views-field.views-field-acnc-search-api-title-sort > a::text').extract(),
             
            'status': i.css('td.views-field.views-field-acnc-search-api-status-normalised::text').extract(),
            
            'size': i.css('td.views-field.views-field-field-charity-size.views-align-center::text').extract(),
             
            'suburb/town': i.css('td.views-field.views-field-acnc-search-api-address-locality::text').extract(),
            
            'state': i.css('td.views-field.views-field-acnc-search-api-address-administrative-area::text').extract(),
             
            'ABN': i.css('td.views-field.views-field-acnc-search-api-abn-sort > a::text').extract(),

            'URL': response.urljoin(i.css('td.views-field.views-field-acnc-search-api-title-sort > a::attr(href)').extract_first())
        }
        yield item
    
    # follow pagination link
    next_page_url = response.css('li.next > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page_url:
        next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on one problem at a time:

Instead of directing outputting the value, use a temporary variable.

```
    for i in response.css('tr.even'):
        abn = i.css('td > a::text')[1].extract()
        if not abn:
            abn = 'Unavailable' # Alternatively, you can use a fallback selector

        item = {
            'company_name': i.css('td > a::text')[0].extract(),
            'ABN': abn,
            #...
        }
        yield item
```

You may also want to check the usage of `extract()` and `extract_first()`. The [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) actually recommends usage of newer `get()` and `getall()` as it is less confusing.

> Scrapy usage docs are now written using .get() and .getall() methods.
>   We feel that these new methods result in a more concise and readable
>   code.

Comment: You are however reproducing the main issue with the original code, which is the misuse of `[n]`.

Comment: So instead I should be attempting to use the tr class as a n then pull the information rather than going through each one individually.

Comment: @Upendra Thanks for your reply, however the if not condition still cause an Error.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of your implementation is that your program can call `extract` method on element that don't exist.

```
for row in response.css('table.views-table tbody tr'):
    i = {}
    # field specific selectors
    i['company_name'], i['ABN'], i['status'], i['size'], i['suburb/town'], i['state'] = row.css('td')
    for key in i.keys():
        i[key] = i[key].css("*::text").get(default="") 
    yield i
```

I used list unpacking to populate item fields ([partially based on this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61366058/10884791))
 as each row of table have strictly 6 columns 
according to [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) - method `get` return result of first match
 it means that with this method you don't need to explicitly use `a` tag inside table cells selector.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your code showed me a neat way of using Scrapy. However, the result missing company_name and ABN.